# Dlpiechart only works on initial view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed the youtube tutorial on *DLPieChart* and I have it working fine. When I put the same code into my own project the pie chart only renders when I set the view controller that the pie chart is on to be the initial view controller. Otherwise pm I only get a greyed out circle.

Any idea why the pie chart doesn't draw unless it's on the initial view controller?

Comment: Well, without a minimum of code, that could be hard to figure out what's your problem.

Comment: @user3593960 how you resolve the problem.?

Answer (score 2):

First create an outlet for the view you created in storyboard.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DLPieChart *pieChartView;
```

Then create a data array for plotting the values in the piechart. Then use the below code to render the piechart.

```
[self.pieChartView renderInLayer:self.pieChartView dataArray:dataArray];
```

This worked perfectly for me. If you are still getting the Piechart plotted with empty slices, share your code.